# AWstats reports URLs appended to other canonical URLs, why?

Tags: url, links, canonical-url, error, awstats

I've been running a site for a while now and my AWstats page is starting to present pages with... some sort of endless stream of references to pages. It's a bit bizarre, I'm not sure what's happened.

[image: AWstats page]

Comment: AWStats is based on your server logs, so someone is visiting those URLs. Possibly a spider. Make sure your website is returning a proper 404 error for URL that doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 1):

When you see subdirectories on top of subdirectories that do not exist, it's most likely a miscoded `relative URL` that a bot is hitting.

I would check your site and update to `absolute URLs`, as they can remedy this problem AND it can help from your entire site being scraped and duplicated at a different domain.

Comment: I would recommend using root relative URLs rather than absolute URLs.   All links to other pages, css, js, and images should start with a slash.  `<a href="/articles.php">Articles</a>`.  I found the site in question and it looks like they are trying to solve this problem using `../articles.php` as the link which may help some, but only for a single directory level.

Comment: Hi @StephenOstermiller, curious why you recommend relative URLs over absolute? I know relative has benefits during development but I feel potential negatives can outweigh the positives.

Comment: Using absolute URLs in every link can substantially increase document sizes.   Root relative links (starting with the slash) have none of the drawbacks of `<a href='article.php'>` style relative links and only add one extra character.   I recommend that they are used in conjunction with rewrite rules to ensure a canonical host name and HTTPS.